# Policy not invoked when using Gate's before()

Tags: php, laravel

I created a policy named `ProjectPolicy` with one function:

```
public function update(User $user, Project $project)
{
    return $project->owner_id == $user->id;
}
```

I registered my policy in my `AuthServiceProvider` as:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Project' => 'App\Policies\ProjectPolicy'
]
```

Also in the `AuthServiceProvider`, I have this:

```
public function boot(Gate $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    $gate->before(function ($user) {
        return $user->isAdmin();
    });
}
```

This is supposed to not apply the policy if the user is admin. But when I do this, it completely takes away the access for non-admin users. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, the `boot` method should be updated as:

```
public function boot(Gate $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    $gate->before(function ($user) {
        return $user->isAdmin() ? true : null;
    });
}
```

From the https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks:

> If the before callback returns a non-null result that result will be
>   considered the result of the check.

Comment: First, I was amazed at how quick you are to answer in `55 secs`

Comment: @ZainFarooq Because OP was ready with Question and answer of it ;).

Comment: @RahulMeshram Ya... This is what I am talking about :)

Comment: This answer actually can help people how `asynchronous` behavior works. Nice effort though!